# Is chometz less of a problem before the 15th of nisson

Tags: halacha, passover, chametz-leaven

Someone told me the he keeps a lot of paisach humros but only starting on the fifteenth of nisson

but on the 14th after midday he is more lax

Is there a source for this that on the 15th it is a bigger violation to eat chomets then on the 14th after noon?

Or that the humras are less important (for what reason?

Hag paisach kosher vsamaiach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Chametz is less of a problem on 14 Nisan. See Rambam Chametz UMatza 1:6-7 that on 14 Nisan consumption of Chametz "only" carries the punishment of lashes whereas on Pesach itself it carries the punishment of Karet.

As an example of a stringency about Chametz which doesn't apply on 14 Nisan: see Shulchan Arukh OC 447:2 that Chametz is nullified in a mixture like a regular prohibited substance on 14 Nisan. On Pesach itself however, Chametz is never nullified. Similarly, everyone agrees the leniencies of Ta'am Lifgam apply to Chametz on 14 Nisan.

Answer (score -1):

There are are varying pasuk I'm that we learn the prohibition of when we are no longer able to eat chametz on the 14th and is discussed at length in gemara pesachim and shulchan aruch. One of them that comes to mind is where it talks about not to slaughter the kardbon pesach over chametzz and from there we learn that one may not longer eat chametz from the time that the kardbon pesach can be shechted. Practically we stop much before chatzos based on other sources.

Comment: I do not seen an answer to my question

Comment: You asked if chometz is less of a problem on the 14th and the halachos is starting the morning of the 14th one may not eat any more chometz starting at a specific time.

Comment: But is it less of a problem?

Comment: No, its the same problem

Comment: This is wrong. It's not the same problem.

Comment: No its correct.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with someone who clearly isn't reading or thinking. This answer is objectively wrong. See mine for details. Chag Sameach.

Comment: Oh wow you told me I'm wrong. FYI chametz doesn't become Batel.

Comment: It does become batel on 14 nisan FYI